# Issues with permissions in restored Google Cloud project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-container-registry, google-cloud-iam

I've recently deleted/restored a GCP project and now I'm having issues with permissions across different services, even though I'm the project `owner`.

Particularly, I can't list the images stored in `Container Registry` and I can list the `Cloud Functions` but I can't access either of them (their details page). Any idea what might cause the issue, or steps I might try?

I don't know how relevant this is, but the project is part of an organisation.

Here's a screenshot with the error for `Container Registry`

[image]

And this is for the `Cloud Functions`

[image]

Comment: How long ago did you delete the project? Edit your question with details and screenshots to better show your issues.

Comment: I deleted and restored in in 15 minutes. It was actually unintended, I was removing the project from the Firebase console - thinking it would remove only the resources associated with Firebase, and that actually removed everything in GCP. I restored the project within 15 minutes. I'll post some screenshots soon

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects): " Billing accounts are immediately disconnected, and must be manually linked again after the project is restored.". Have you reconnected billing to your restored project? Also, you can ask [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) to check if billing was already reconnected to your restored project.

Comment: Sometimes it may take time for the APIs to be fully functional when restoring the project (all APIs need to re-initiate and settings restored). When have you restored your project?

Comment: Yes, billing is enabled. It happened around this time yesterday.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Have  Google Cloud Support  confirmed that there's no issue with your billing account? Do you have any logs that could be related to this issue?

Comment: I still do, yes. The billing account has no issues, it's being used across other projects as well. No logs.. any pointers? Where would I get some relevant logs from?

Comment: In some cases there could be an issue on GCP side, so it's always better to ask [Google Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) if everything okay with your billing and if there no other issues. As I can see you have only this project restored, so other projects could work without any issues. Have a look at the documentation [Cloud logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs) and [Cloud Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit). If you found no clues or log records you should reach [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support).